# How to create a trigger to script in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I tried to add a trigger for filling form,
according to this guidance:
https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2018/09/17/auto-fill-google-doc-from-google-form-submission/

After writing the script, I tried to add the trigger as explained in this link.
Unfortunately, I receive a message of "This app isn't verified
This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer."

[image: r]

I would appreciate some guidance,
Thanks

Comment: Click advanced and install the trigger

Answer (score 1):

It's common to receive this warning in Apps Script if the app needs to access sensitive OAuth scopes, depending on whether the app is verified, and depending on what type of account the publisher and the user have (G Suite accounts are less likely to experience this, while Gmail accounts will always experience this if the client is not verified, even if it's the same account that is used to publish the app).

[Here is a table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#applicability) that illustrates all the possible situations.

If you trust the publisher, though, and specifically, if the publisher is yourself, you can just click `Advanced` and then select `Go to {your-project-name} (unsafe)` to authorize and run the script.

#### Reference:

- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)
- [Apps Script: OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)